# Make sprite disappear in collision?

Tags: java, collision, invisible

How to make the coins disappear when Mario intersects them? I figured out the intersection with rectangles, now I want to make the coins gone.

```
        Rectangle m = new Rectangle(x, y, 37, 51);
        Rectangle c = new Rectangle(a, b, 32, 38);

        if (m.intersects(c)) {
        System.out.println("? How to make coin disappear?");    
        }
       else if (c.intersects(m))
        { System.out.println("??");

        }
```

m = mario
c = coin

The program works because it gives the string output whenever Mario touches a coin.

Comment: The answer would depend on how you are managing them in the first place.  One might "assume" that would use a `List` in which the coins can be added and, when you detect a collision, removed - this would form part of the state model used by the engine during it's update and paint phases

Comment: I am using a loop to create coins. I will have to set the amount of coins always. The code is under ActionEvent. I used Graphics2D to get the images on the screen.